# Show unused Typescript variables in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to show unused Typescript variables in Visual Studio Code, without blocking the compilation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, latest VS code highlights unused blocks including unused variables.

Comment: Just update your VS code.

Comment: Here's what I just did that worked: (1) installed latest VSCode, (2) installed latest TypeScript. Unused variables and imports are now correctly greyed out, even with the latest TSLint which doesn't support checking for unused imports/variables without type-check (you can use 4.5.1 for that).

Comment: my vscode in lastest version dont show unused vaiables

Answer (score -2):

To report the unused variables as warnings when compiling the code, set the following option in tslint.json:

```
"no-unused-variable": true
```

Comment: "no-unused-variable" is deprecated